# How to upload image file with additional information like label or alt value in express-fileupload?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express-fileupload

**I am trying to add a label text in file object but when uploading in node.js through express-fileupload. Its uploading the file but label is missing.**

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

const imageLabelChanger = (index, e) => {
   const value = e.target.value;
    //insert label and value for specifix image by index

   files[index].file.label = value;
   setFiles(files);
 }; 
 const FD = new FormData();

 const createProduct = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    for (let i in files) {
        FD.append("productImageArray", files[i].file);
    }
    dispatch(addProductImage(paramId, FD));
};
```

**With this code i am getting the files object**

> console.log(files)

```
output: [
        {
            "id": 7,
            valid: true,
            "file": File{
            label: "oxygen blue",
            lastModified: 1642222607314,
            lastModifiedDate: Sat Jan 15 2022 10:26:47 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {},
            name: "galaxy-8.jpeg",
            size: 8433,
            type: "image/jpeg",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            valid: true,
            "file": File{
            lastModified: 1642222607314,
            lastModifiedDate: Sat Jan 15 2022 10: 26: 47 GMT+0530(India Standard Time) {},
            name: "galaxy-9.jpeg",
            size: 9458,
            type: "image/jpeg",
        }
    ]
```

**After file upload i am getting file object but not getting the actual files object what i was send using formData,label key and its value is missing**

> console.log(req.files.productImages)

```
    output: [
                {
                    lastModified: 1642222607314,
                    lastModifiedDate: Sat Jan 15 2022 10:26:47 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {},
                    name: "galaxy-8.jpeg",
                    size: 8433,
                    type: "image/jpeg",
                    data:
Binary('/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAoHBwgHBgoICAgLCgoLDhgQDg0NDh0VFhEYIx8lJCIfIiEmKzcvJik0KSEiMEExNDk7...', 0)
                },
                {
                    lastModified: 1642222607314,
                    lastModifiedDate: Sat Jan 15 2022 10: 26: 47 GMT+0530(India Standard Time) {},
                    name: "galaxy-9.jpeg",
                    size: 9458,
                    type: "image/jpeg",
                    data:
Binary('/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAoHBwgHBgoICAgLCgoLDhgQDg0NDh0VFhEYIx8lJCIfIiEmKzcvJik0KSEiMEExNDk7...', 0)
                }
            ]
```

Please help me how can i make that things i think this problem is with req.files may be it doesn't take any extra property so if there has any way to achieve this.

**Advance Thank you**

Answer (score 1):

I a, not sure if this is applicable to your situation but I usually attach a 'body' object with the additional details when sending files. Something like this:

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

const imageLabelChanger = (index, e) => {
   const value = e.target.value;
    //insert label and value for specifix image by index

   files[index].file.label = value;
   setFiles(files);
 }; 
 const FD = new FormData();

 const createProduct = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    for (let i in files) {
        FD.append("productImageArray", files[i].file);
        FD.append("productImageArrayLabels", files[i].file.label); // Add another property to the formData here
    }
    dispatch(addProductImage(paramId, FD));
};
```

That way you'd have a files object and a body object on the server:

1. Files: productImageArray
2. File Labels: productImageArrayLabels

Comment: it's not worked by the way thanks for trying to solve

Comment: Are you using express/node to handle the data on the server? If so, What package are you using to handle the files? Multer?

Comment: actually i have tried both express-fileupload and multer. Both are not providing any extra property. the packages return { name, md5, data, truncated, encoding, size }
But i want label or anything where can i store the image with label

Comment: I think I see now. Are you changing one label at a time or can multiple files sent to the server at any given time?

Comment: multiple files . Your solution also needed but in backend we need to assign the label according to thier index. Actually what i was thought multer doesn't provide the way so we need to make it this way.